# WPF get all bindings pointing to a property in my model

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a scenario like this

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding WorldConfig}">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Width}">
</StackPanel>
```

I want to get all bindings pointing to "Width" property of WorldConfig object

I wrote a function for this as

```
BindingUtil.GetAllBindings(WorldConfig, "Width")
```

but it searches through all windows to find a FrameworkElement whose DataContext equals to the first parameter and then searches for a BindingExpression whose ResolvedSourcePropertyName equals to the second parameter. And it is quite inefficient. I thought of caching the results but then any change to bindings in runtime will break it.

I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this.

I'm thinking that these BindingExpressions must be stored in somewhere I can query but I can't find it, only search results I'm getting for my searches are about how to do the opposite of this.

Comment: You might be able to write a subclass of `Binding` that keeps a static collection of all instances, though I wouldn't care to write the code to prune the obsolete ones. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: In `public string this[string columnName] {get{.....}}` I need to validate two properties by comparing them to each other but before that I want to check if they are valid themselves thus I need to get their ValidationErrors in that context

Comment: That's all viewmodel stuff. Why would you want to get bindings involved?

Comment: My properties are integer and I want to avoid doing the model validation if the bound textbox doesn't contain a valid integer. I can't detect if an integer is written incorrectly inside my model without accessing the ValidationError

Comment: If I understand correctly, it sounds like [`Binding.ValidationRules`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.110).aspx) might solve your problem.